# Induced matrix on degrees Macaulay2

Tags: commutative-algebra, macaulay2

I would like to compute the matrix associated with a map between graded modules with help of Macaulay2. For instance, if I have $R = \mathbb{Q}[x,y]$, and a map $\times (x+y): R \to R$, I would like to compute the matrix $[\times (x+y)]: R_1 \to R_2$. Clearly, if we order the basis of $R_1$ as $\{x,y\}$ and  of $R_2$ as {x^2,xy, y^2}$, the induced map is

$\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 1  \\
1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$.

I would like to know if there is a command that make this computation for me in Macaulay2 or SageMath.

Comment: `R = QQ[x,y]; (x+y)*basis(1,R) // basis(2,R)`

Comment: great many thanks!